# Serialize List[Any] to/from Json in Scala using Jackson

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I've got a case class I'd like to be able to serialize and deserialize from JSON:

```
case class Foo(values: List[Any])
```

e.g.

```
Foo(List(new DateTime))
```

In this scenario, the DateTime gets serialized as a long, and hence deserialized as a Long rather than a dateTime.

Like this:

```
{"values":[1315343106920]}
```

Suggestions? I think what needs to happen is that the name of the class (e.g. DateTime) needs to get serialized out, and checked on deserialization.  The list of types I might put in the values list is finite/small.

Perhaps like this:

```
{"values":[{"DateTime":1315343106920}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to what seems like a brute force solution to just do manual serialization with Jackson, e.g.

```
  def serializeNode(foo: Foo, mapper: ObjectMapper): JsonNode = {
    val n = mapper.createObjectNode()

    val valuesNode = mapper.createArrayNode()
    n.put("values", valuesNode)
    foo.values.foreach { value =>
      val nd = mapper.createObjectNode

      value match {
        case intValue: Int => nd.put("int", intValue)
        case decimalValue: BigDecimal => nd.put("decimal", decimalValue.bigDecimal)
        case booleanValue: Boolean => nd.put("boolean", booleanValue)
        case strValue: String => nd.put("string", strValue)
        case dtValue: DateTime => nd.put("datetime", _dtFmt.print(dtValue))          
        case _ => sys.error("Unexpected value type: " + value)
      }
      valuesNode.add(nd) 
    }
    n
  }

  def serialize(foo: Foo): String = {
    val out = new StringWriter
    val generator = new JsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(out)
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper
    generator.setCodec(mapper)

    generator.writeTree(serializeNode(foo, mapper))     
    out.toString
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if it'd help, but Jerkson [https://github.com/codahale/jerkson] is a Scala-specific extension of Jackson, and might handle this case better than plain Jackson? There is also Jackson extension module [https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala] that similarly aims to improve scala-specific usage.